# how to convert classname to classid and store into DB in yii framework

Tags: yii

i am developing application by using yii framework, i have one table called "studentinformation", i have some columns in that table like

```
 id  name   mothername   phone        classid   parentname      email
 1.  xxxxx    asdf       9658741230     2         pqrs        xy@gmail.com
```

and also i have one more table called classname table

```
 classid  classname
    1.      class1
    2.      class2
    3.      class3
```

i set classid as foreign key,i am trying to upload excel files instead of filling the forms. this is my excel format data

```
 id  name   mothername   phone         classid    parentname      email
 1.  xxxxx    asdf       9658741230     class1      pqrs      xy@gmail.com
```

in above table i gave classname instead od classid because user is comfortable for classname only not classid but i need to store classid to Database

In my controller  i am getting value from excel file like

```
    $newmodel->name=$data[0];
        $newmodel->mothername=$data[1];
        $newmodel->phone=$data[2];
        //i am getting classname instead of classid  
        $classname=$data[11];
        //i need to convert from classname to classid 
       $classdet = Classdetails::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"classname=>'$classname'"));
      foreach(classdet as $val)
      {
             $classid[] = $val->classid;
      }
   $newmodel->classid = $classid[0];
```

i am not getting correct output could you please help me...

Comment: Why are you getting `$class->class->classid` instead of `$class->classid` ? Also, try not to use the keyword `class`, it is confusing, `$classDetails` would be better.

Comment: @JelledeFries i edited my question just check it and let me know whether it is correct or not

Comment: Well, you can just use `find` instead of `findAll`, this way you only get one record. then you can do a `$classdet->classid` instead of the `foreach` loop. But I don't see a reason why your code shouldn't work. what is the undesired output you are getting?

Comment: Also try a `Classdetails::model()->findByAttributes(array("classname"=>$classname))` because your condition is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, from the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) `findAll` wants the following parameters:

1. `$condition` (mixed)
2. `$params` (array)

Like I suggested in my comment try to use:

```
$classdet = Classdetails::model()->findByAttributes(array("classname"=>$classname));
```

And it should work.
Your code should look like this:

```
$newmodel->name=$data[0];
$newmodel->mothername=$data[1];
$newmodel->phone=$data[2];
$classname=$data[11];
$classdet = Classdetails::model()->findByAttributes(array("classname"=>$classname));
$newmodel->classid = $classdet->classid;
//save or show your new model.
```

You may want to put in some logic on what happens if a `classname` is not found in the database. But I don't know if this is a valid scenario.

like this:

```
$newmodel->name=$data[0];
$newmodel->mothername=$data[1];
$newmodel->phone=$data[2];
$classname=$data[11];
$classdet = Classdetails::model()->findByAttributes(array("classname"=>$classname));
$newmodel->classid = 0;
if($classdet){
    $newmodel->classid = $classdet->classid;
}
//save or show your new model.
```

This way your `$newmodel->classid` will be set to 0 by default.
if your `$classdet` not is `null` it will set the proper value.

Comment: i am trying as what you said but i am getting error "Trying to get property of non-object" what have to  do?

Comment: Well, this means that your `$classdet` is `null` which means the `$classname` you are looking for is not present in your database.

Comment: ya it is working fine but incase i didn't enter classname in my excel file that time it should store classid as 0  how to do it

Comment: my last question i have status and schoolid  in my classdetails table if i want to check schoolid =1 and status=1 with in this                        $classdet = Classdetails::model()->findByAttributes(array("classname"=>$classname)); what i need to do

Comment: Just add them to the array the same way we did with `$classname` and read the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail) if you are not sure.